# react-native-community/asyncStorage removeItem causes program to behave weirdly

Tags: react-native, axios, interceptor, asyncstorage

I have this little code snippet executed during the user logout.

```
 async function logoutAction(props) {
  removeUser();
  props.logoutUser();
}
```

The function inside removeUser() is as :

```
 export const removeUser = async () => {
  try {
    await AsyncStorage.removeItem(Constant.storage.user_data);
    await AsyncStorage.removeItem(Constant.storage.token);
    await AsyncStorage.removeItem(Constant.storage.notification_token);
    return true;
  } catch (exception) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

This clears user related data from local storage.
Similarly, `props.logoutUser()` is a reference call to reducer which sets loggedIn status to false.

I'm having this issue that if the `removeUser()` function is called once, the axios http requests do not enter the interceptors anymore and every request catches an error 'undefined'.  If this method is removed though, everything works fine.
I can get it to working state then by removing the interceptors once, performing a request and then adding the interceptors again, which I found after hours of here and there.

My interceptors are:

```
    export const requestInterceptor = axios.interceptors.request.use(
  async config => {
    const token = await getToken();
    if (token != '') {
      config.headers.Authorization = token;
    }
    console.log('axios request', config);
    return config;
  },
  error => {
    // console.warn('on request error')
    return Promise.reject(error);
  },
);

export const responseInterceptor = axios.interceptors.response.use(
  function(response) {
    console.log('axios response', response);
    // console.warn('on response success', response.status)
    return response;
  },
  async function(error) {
    if (error.response.status === 401) {
      //logout user
      return;
    }
    return Promise.reject(error);
  },
);
```

I am using the `@react-native-community/AsyncStorage` package for maintaining local storage. I suspect that the issue might be in the `removeItem` method but I'm unsure as the official docs don't contain the `removeItem` method, or in the interceptor which doesn't seem faulty to me anyways.

What am I doing wrong here?? Please show me some light..

Comment: what does `getToken()` do? and do none of those logs show up after you log out?

Comment: The get token fetches the token stored in localstorage and it does that pretty well. I haven't issued a http request in logouts as of now but in other requests it logs all of them good.

Comment: yeah, but if that's erroring out because the token no longer exists then it could be breaking your interceptors. how did you set it up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was quite silly and did not even concern `AsyncStorage` or `removeItem` and as `Matt Aft` pointed out in the comment, it was due to the call for token in the interceptor after it had been removed while logging out. So, replacing

```
const token = await getToken();
    if (token != '') {
      config.headers.Authorization = token;
    }
```

by

```
  await getToken()
          .then(token => {
            config.headers.Authorization = token;
          })
          .catch(_ => {
            console.log('no token');
          });
```

in the interceptor and returning promise from the `getToken` method did the thing.
Thanks to `Matt` and `高鵬翔`.

Comment: Cheers, you can accept this as an answer to finish this question lol.

Comment: Oh~! It have this rules! I accept my own answer after I asked for a long time, because finally I solved by myself, so sad lol.

Comment: @Raavan np, and yeah the smallest bugs always take the longest to figure out haha

Answer (score 1):

Or maybe try add a `await` before `removeUser();` ?

```js
async function logoutAction(props) {
  await removeUser();
  props.logoutUser();
}
```

Comment: yeah I tried that too and did it again to ensure. Same result. :(

Comment: It do have removeItem function in [Doc](https://react-native-community.github.io/async-storage/docs/api#removeitem) . Is the key correct?

Comment: Oops I missed the API part of the doc , but anyways the key is correct.

Comment: When I console.log within the removeUser method, it successfully reaches before the return true; statement and returns true. And then the aftermath

Comment: Or maybe just use [setItem](https://react-native-community.github.io/async-storage/docs/api#setitem) to value "" none of it? And change the condition to check if get it equal to  "" ?

Comment: I'd actually given a thought to this, but didnt try it. I did it now and yes it works. I think I'm going to stick with this for now until I find a proper solution. Thanks.:)

Comment: ok~ good luck!  If you found it, you could update a new answer lol.

Comment: the issue is `token != ''`, if you're deleting then token returns null and still running that code. maybe try removeItem but change this to `if (token)`. otherwise  getToken might be erroring out

Comment: Or you just change to `(token!= "" || token!= null)` ?

Comment: yep, `if (token)` may work, have try to check, if now work could use like above.

Comment: So I said before maybe use `setItem` to ""  is want to avoid this situation. > <"

Comment: @MattAft yes that was the thing. I cant believe I got stuck in something such silly for a whole day. Thank you.